# jQuery "each" method

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I'm a javascript beginner, and I'm having some trouble using jQuery's "each" method.  I have a gallery module on a Joomla site that functions as a simple image slider. I added some code to allow a lightbox on the linked images.  What I would like to do now is copy the thumbnail caption (that the module currently adds) to the Title attribute in the link so it shows up in the lightbox for each image.

Here's how the HTML is structured...

```
<div class="camera_wrap" id="camera_wrap_106">
<div class="cameraContents">
    <div class="cameraContent">
        <a class="camera_link" href="lightbox-large.jpg" title="This is where i need the caption"></a>
        <div class="camera_caption">
            <div>This is the caption</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cameraContent">
        <a class="camera_link" href="lightbox-large.jpg" title="This is where i need the caption"></a>
        <div class="camera_caption">
            <div>This is the caption</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cameraContent">
        <a class="camera_link" href="lightbox-large.jpg" title="This is where i need the caption"></a>
        <div class="camera_caption">
            <div>This is the caption</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've gotten the code this far, but it only copies the first caption div to each title attribute rather than executing it on each instance. Not sure if this is even the best start...

```
$("#camera_wrap_106 .cameraContent").each(function() {
    $("#camera_wrap_106 a.camera_link").attr('title', $("#camera_wrap_106 .camera_caption div").html());
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the callback function of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("#camera_wrap_106 .cameraContent a.camera_link").attr('title',function(){
    return $.trim($(this).next().text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nSj8h/

Or if you wanted to use your each statement just set the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) in your selectors

```
$("#camera_wrap_106 .cameraContent").each(function() {
    $("a.camera_link",this).attr('title', $(".camera_caption div",this).text());
});
```

Adding the context in your selector is the same thing as using find

```
$('element',context) == $(context).find('element')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baLmn/

Answer (score 2):

You should use `this` :

```
$("#camera_wrap_106 .cameraContent").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).html());
});
```

`.each` provides the element in the iteration as context of the function (i.e. `this`).

It's also provided as second argument (the first one being the index), which means you could also have written this :

```
$("#camera_wrap_106 .cameraContent").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).attr('title', $(element).html());
});
```

Comment: or `$("#camera_wrap_106 .cameraContent").attr("title", function () {
    return $(this).html();
});`

Comment: @Tomalak Right. Even if it doesn't explain .each it's obviously the cleaner solution in that exact case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, the code given is doing the same thing. For some reason it's still copying the first caption div to each Title attribute.

Comment: Are you sure ? I don't see how that's possible. Don't you have a cache problem.